# Issues with React Native CLI: Google Maps continuously loading after building APK

Tags: react-native, google-maps, build, apk, react-native-maps

I'm using React Native CLI for my project.
The maps component functions correctly during development using npm run android.
However, after building the APK and deploying it on a device, the maps component fails to load properly.
I've ensured that all necessary permissions and configurations are set correctly in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
I've also verified that the API keys and dependencies are properly configured.
There are no error messages provided, and the loading spinner simply persists indefinitely.

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.my"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="28"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="key"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"
```

I need to obtain the device's location and display it on the map.